# What is the best async loading (view)models strategy when using MVVMCross

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I have been working with MVVM for a while (comming from XAML) and I'm using MVVMCross at this moment for a Xamarin project.

What is the best (a good) strategy to load data into the ViewModels\Models in a async way?

PS: I want to prevent long frozen screens when navigating, I'm looking to navigate first and the async load the data.

Comment: Just load your data within async methods. There's no explicit strategy despite this, that's all you need.

Comment: Just use the Start or Init methods.

Comment: OK, I have been doing the same thing for years now, so no better strategy then async load after the views and viewmodels have been setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just to clearify;

The ViewModels in MVVMCross (MvxViewModel) do have some handy override methods.

Init for picking up navigation parameters
Start to do everything else after the ViewModel is innitualized.

To load ViewModel data in a more UX friendly way I was happy with the following in my ViewModels

> ```
>     public override async void Start()
>     {
>         base.Start();
>         myViewModel = await LoadViewModel();
>     }
> ```

Thanks Thomas and Cheesebaron for the comments